# Language to regular expression

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Having difficulty grasping the concept of how a language and a regular expression are related. For example:

(In all cases, the alphabet is $\{0,1\}$)

The language $L = \{100,10,011\}$ ------> Regular expression.

So far, I have:

$(0+1)$ since you can have either $0$ or $1$ in the first part...but...I'm not sure what would follow after that...I've tried making a DFA for it but I feel like I'm overcomplicating it. Any help would be great since I'm fairly confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the language is finite like you have given in the question then regular expression is simple just write all string separated by $+$(union).
So $$r = 100 + 10 + 011$$
further you have something common in first two string so 
$$r= 10(0+\epsilon) + 011$$

> I feel like I'm overcomplicating it.

For that You need to learn three operators $*$ , $+$ and $.$ properly & understand the language given then It will be easy for you to make a regular expression without making a D.F.A..

Comment: So, can you concatenate as many strings as you want? For example:  r = (blah + blah + blah +......)

Comment: If the language is finite then we can.